# Parallelizing large loops and improving cache accesses

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I have a code like the following which I am using to find prime numbers (using Eratosthenes sieve) within a range, and using OpenMP to parallelize. Before this, I have a preprocessing stage where I am flagging off all even numbers, and multiples of 3 and 5 so that I have to do less work in this stage. 
The shared L3 cache of the testbed is 12MB, and the physical memory is 32 GB. I am using 12 threads. The `flag` array is `unsigned char`.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < range; i++)
{
     for (j = 5; j < range; j+=2)
     {
         if( flag[i] == 1 && i*j < range )
             if ( flag[i*j] == 1 )
                 flag[i*j] = 0;
      }
 }
```

This program works well for ranges less than 1,000,000...but after that the execution time shoots up for larger ranges; eg, for `range = 10,000,000` this program takes around 70 mins (not fitting in cache?). I have modified the above program to incorporate loop tiling so that it could utilize the cache for any loop range, but even the blocking approach seems to be time consuming. Interchanging the loops also do not help for large ranges.

How do I modify the above code to tackle large ranges? And how could I rewrite the code to make it fully parallel (`range` and `flag` [since the `flag` array is quite large so I can't declare it private] is shared)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I just noticed a few easy speedups in your code. So I'll mention these before I get into the fast algorithm:

1. Use a bit-field instead of a char array. You can save a factor of 8 in memory.
2. Your outer loop is running over all integers. Not just the primes. After each iteration, start from the first number that hasn't been crossed off yet. (that number will be prime)

I'm suggesting this because you mentioned that it take 70 min. on a (pretty powerful) machine to run `N = 10,000,000`. That didn't look right, since my own trivial implementation can do `N = 2^32` in under 20 seconds on a laptop - single-threaded, no source-level optimizations. So then I noticed that you missed a few basic optimizations.

Here's the efficient solution. But it takes some work.

The key is to recognize that the Eratosthenes Sieve only needs to go up to sqrt(N) of your target size. In other words, you only need to run the sieve on all prime numbers up to sqrt(N) before you are done.

So the trick is to first run the algorithm on sqrt(N). Then dump all the primes into a dense data structure. By pre-computing all the needed primes, you break the dependency on the outer-loop.

Now, for the rest of the numbers from sqrt(N) - N, you can cross off all numbers that are divisible by any prime in your pre-computed table. Note that this is independent for all the remaining numbers. So the algorithm is now embarrassingly parallel.

To be efficient, this needs to be done using "mini"-sieves on blocks that fit in cache. To be even more efficient, you should compute and cache the reciprocals of all the primes in the table. This will help you efficiently find the "initial offsets" of each prime when you fill out each "mini-sieve".

The initial step of running the algorithm sequential for sqrt(N) will be very fast since it's only sqrt(N). The rest of the work is completely parallelizable.

In the fully general case, this algorithm can be applied recursively on the initial sieve, but that's generally overkill.

Comment: Yes, I have followed your advice to re-write my code, the performance is still not as good as yours, but it has drastically got down for a single thread (50s for single thread and 5 for 12 threads). I am sure I could tune my code more, and would include in the edits when I'm satisfied with the results.

Comment: Which optimizations have you implemented? I just looked at my own implementation. It's single-threaded and doesn't precompute the sqrt(N) table. But it uses a "compressed" bitfield where each bit represents an odd number. (So it's 16x more memory efficient than a char-array.) For 2^31, I get 16 seconds on a Core i7 720QM. (http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?221773-New-Multi-Threaded-Pi-Program-Faster-than-SuperPi-and-PiFast&p=4230543&viewfull=1#post4230543)

Comment: I precompute the sqrt(N) table (this process has loop carried dependencies, so is not parallel at present), and on the second part I just find primes from sqrt(N) to N as you had advised (this is fully parallel, no dependencies between the loops). I am not sure how to implement the compressed bitfield, but I will check out the url and do some googling. Thanks.

Comment: How are you implementing the step of crossing out everything that is divisible by anything in the table? A simple loop of divisions will be very slow - slower than the straight-forward approach.

Comment: Yes you're correct, I am doing that, but I'm break-ing off with the first successful division, so I am not going from 2 to sqrt(N) for every i in sqrt(N) -> N. So you're performing the sieve once...

Comment: My current implementation is just an optimized straight-forward approach. (which is not parallelizable) The sqrt(N) table approach (when done correctly) is much faster. Although I haven't fully implemented it, I can see it going sub 4-seconds on my laptop for N = 2^31.

Comment: Considering mine is a naive approach, upon using bit shifts instead of modulo op I was able to bring down the time further.